# Changing Background Image using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <style></style>
<script src="main.js">
    function myFunction() {
        document.body.style.background = "url('images/img_tree.png')"
    }
</script>

<body>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Set background</button>
</body></html>
```

Why won't this work? I am using the brackets IDE currently.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `src="main.js"` from your script tag

Does this fix it ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <style></style>
  <script>
      function myFunction() {
          document.body.style.background = "url('https://fsb.zobj.net/crop.php?r=e9wUbuA4gtFtr46UA2PE5GMcriRP4IPSzPTWOBs82VJEK_zIJcyRW5kh6JE_GrxfEmFki6gil-dD-LL5eMpMNcj5Sjw4u4Y6MwkMhR-1WlgJ50l6FRXVLRylR_2lbwvcMeLEOIUkEzNPODPaAqMfI4ClDs3vu9s3Z2s8bF55uCt0KPXzxye5ueQyfDyFFgfks2aGkOwr7pURMvK_')"
      }
  </script>

  <body>
      <button onclick="myFunction()">Set background</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete src="main.js" on script tag

if you want to use main.js file. you have to add extra script tag

like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <style></style>
<script src="main.js"></script>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        document.body.style.background = "url('images/img_tree.png')"
    }
</script>

<body>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Set background</button>
</body></html>
```

Or you can add myFunction on your main.js file

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you set `src="main.js"`, in this case all script inside script tag will be not execute, it only execute javascript in `main.js` file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <style></style>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        document.body.style.background = "url('https://geology.com/world/world-map-360.gif')"
    }
</script>

<body>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Set background</button>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code snippet for the add background image.

```js
// Sets the background image
const setBackground = (image) => {
  document.body.style.background = "url('"+IMAGE_URLS.[image]+"')";
};
```

Comment: “While this code may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. ” :)

Comment: This won't work. You've changed the function name (for no apparent reason) so the attempt to call it will fail. You've changed the value from being a hard coded string (which was fine) to one generated by mashing three different strings together … and only of them depends on a variable which isn't defined.

Comment: Just try this. This is working!